# CSV file number format is different in EXCEL and Notepad

Tags: php, excel, csv, formatting

I have received a report as an CSV file. It contains the contact names and contact numbers.
When i try to open the file in Excel, it displays the contact number like "912224308876". But, if i try to open that file in notepad or try to read in PHP then i get that contact number in different format i.e. "9.12224E+11".

Does any one has idea to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Format your cell as number in excel, then save and it should be ok

Comment: PHP aparently interprets the column as floating point value instead of  `string` what you want. So probably it would be easiest to just read the file line by line and parse it manually. That way you have full control and don't fly in the blind.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Excel treats long numbers as floating point and converts them to scientific notation, often in a lossy way. As described below, the best options are either to use a TXT extension instead of CSV and use the import wizard (which allows you to specify column types), or to use a formula instead of a number to fake out Excel.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exceldev/thread/64c1ee52-eb53-4202-bb27-d9b08d3bd60a/